# Slower download speed compared to Windows on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, drivers, 20.04

I have just installed Ubuntu 20.04 and I am facing a pretty big issue. My download speeds are really low compared to the Windows 10 that I have installed on dual-boot setup.

This is the speed I'm getting in Windows.
[image]

And this is what I'm getting in Ubuntu.
[image]

My network adapter is Lenovo RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller.

I have tried changing the DNS options but that doesn't help.

Device is a Lenovo Y700-15ISK Laptop.

Output `lshw`:

```
*-network DISABLED
       description: Wireless interface
       product: QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0
       logical name: wlp8s0
       version: 30
       serial: cc:b0:da:b7:60:65
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath10k_pci driverversion=5.4.0-29-generic firmware=WLAN.TF.2.1-00021-QCARMSWP-1 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:142 memory:94000000-941fffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:09:00.0
       logical name: enp9s0
       version: 15
       serial: c8:5b:76:3e:55:50
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8168 driverversion=8.048.00-NAPI duplex=full ip=192.168.100.2 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:131 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:94304000-94304fff memory:94300000-94303fff
```

Also, the `ifconfig` shows a lot of dropped RX packages that are increasing as we speak:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments...

- 20.04, booting from the 5.4.0-29 kernel netted very poor ethernet download speeds
- tried the r8168-dkms driver with no improvement in download speeds
- updating to a 5.6.11 kernel and the download speeds were back to normal, but the Nvidia/CUDA stuff broke, no surprise, and will need an update
- rebooted to the 5.4.0-29 kernel and confirmed that Nvidia works again, and download speeds reverted
- purged the 5.6.11 kernel packages
- no newer 5.4.0 kernels were available to install
- booted to an older 5.4.0-26 kernel and download speeds were still low
- Summary... the 5.4.0 kernels don't work well with this (version 15) r8168/r8169 ethernet card

**Update #1:**

*Removed nvidia driver and installed nvidia-dkms-440 from their repository and then installed 5.5.19 and the driver built just fine on this kernel version. And now both my internet and my graphics card are working.*

Comment: `the 5.4.0 kernels don't work well with r8168/r8169 ethernet cards` that is wrong.

Comment: @Pilot6 Please explain. I spent a better part of yesterday trying to get 5.4.0 to work with this card. 5.6.11 and 5.5.19 work fine.

Comment: There is no "this card" in your answer. There is a ton of revisions, most of them work perfectly with all kernels. If a specific new revision doesn't work well, there is almost always a source code of `rtl8168` at relatek site. It may be not the latest in Ubuntu repos.

Comment: The latest is in `groovy` repo. You can try it. Version `8.048.02`

Comment: @Pilot6 We first tried the 048 version, and that didn't work. Then we went on a kernel expedition, and found what we found. The "this card" refers to ethernet cards driven by the r8169 or r8168-dkms drivers.

Comment: Try `048.02` version.

Comment: @Pilot6 OP is working with 5.5.19 and working Nvidia drivers. I wouldn't image they'd break that just to try 048.02 from a development release of Ubuntu.

Comment: That won't break anything. It is just a bit newer driver from realtek. It will build on 5.4-5.6 kernels.

Comment: @Pilot6 OP had 5.4.0-29 before. All 5.4.0 kernels after that didn't build at https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/. My answer is working, and was accepted.

Comment: So this is a good catch that new kernels have a fix. But general assumption that the 5.4 kernel don't support ALL rtl8168 cards is wrong. I am using it on all computers with no problems.

Comment: But as you say *"It will build on 5.4-5.6 kernels."*... the OP had 5.4.0-26 and -29... not 5.4-5.6 whatever that is. Quit nitpicking.

Comment: 5.4.0-26 is a 5.4 kernel.

Comment: @Pilot6 Correct. 5.4.0-26 and -29 are 5.4 kernels, **that didn't work with r8169 or r8168-dkms (048-01 probably)**... so whether we update the kernel to 5.5.19, or use the r8168-dkms (048-02) from groovy... the end result is the same... 20.04 is broken with respect to this configuration. Enough already.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install the latest `rtl8168-dkms` from `groovy`.

http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/r/r8168/r8168-dkms_8.048.02-1_all.deb

Comment: This 20.04 configuration didn't work with the original r8169 driver, or the r8168-dkms driver from the focal repos.

Comment: What is "this 20.04" configuration? There is a new upstream driver release that can address the issue. It is also fixed in newer kernels as you already noticed. But it is more handy to use Ubuntu kernels with a dkms driver, than to use mainline and update it manually. So it's worth trying.

Comment: "this 20.04" refers to the OPs installed OS. Sheesh.

Comment: Installed the dkms you've recommended and my internet still works fine as it worked with the r8169 packed with the 5.5.19 kernel. So, for me, the kernel was the issue here, not the drivers for the card. Thanks to everybody for help!

Comment: And what if you test the driver on the standard Ubuntu 5.4.0-x kernel? That was the point of using the driver. @Andrei-EduardLică

Comment: UPDATE: rebooted after driver install and using r8168 driver the problem came back, even on 5.5.19. Reverting to r8169 fixes the problem.

Comment: Maybe the problem is unrelated to the driver. Check the cable, etc.

Comment: If you look at the lshw output, you'll see that it's probably not a cable problem, as it's connecting at 1G.

Comment: @Pilot6 No need to do that. Everything is working fine right now.

Comment: Yes, r8169 and kernel 5.5.19 work.

Comment: It may have to do with the hardware/firmware revision of the ethernet card. OP's is version: 15. I have 0c, but haven't been able to try 20.04 yet... I finally got the upgrade notification yesterday...

Answer (score 0):

r8168 does not work with RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller.

Do this:

```
$ sudo modprobe -r r8168
$ sudo modprobe r8169
```

To replace r8168 with r8169

Answer (score 0):

My issue with this network adapter was exactly the same. Solved it by installing the latest r8168 driver from here: https://github.com/mtorromeo/r8168/releases

Found the solution here: https://askubuntu.com/a/1328041/1008529